# CSS overflow : how to show bottom element

Tags: html, css

I  just want to show the bottom content .Initially I gave the hidden value to the overflow-x and overflow-y property then I want to show the content which is situated in the bottom of y direction.
Here's my code:

```
<div class="parent">
        <p class="child">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, sed. Ducimus at ex quo tenetur
            accusamus cupiditate accusantium officiis. Recusandae libero natus similique ea amet aut quae accusamus,
            neque ad!
        </p>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.parent {
            position: relative;
            border: 2px solid black;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }

        .child {
            position: absolute;
            transform: translate(50px, -50px);
        }
```

You can check [codepen](https://codepen.io/nasim67reja/pen/QWOYEbp)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is not the final result you expect, but is an aproach. What I'm done here is create a `.wrapper` in order to hide scrollbar (can you see how in the attached CSS). And then just give `overflow-y: scroll` to the `.parent`.

If it is not the result you want please come back with more information.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  height: inherit;
  padding-right: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
        <p class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, sed. Ducimus at ex quo tenetur accusamus cupiditate accusantium officiis. Recusandae libero natus similique ea amet aut quae accusamus, neque ad!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I want to show the content of the bottom but without scrolling. I only accept the bottom  content overflow.  all content will be hidden except the bottom content. I want to show the bottom content outside the parent box

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure it out what do you want to accomplish. Could you attach an image or something that can visually give us a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need to keep the container at the current size - if you do, then use `overflow-y: scroll`. Otherwise, here is an alternate styling that doesn't restrict the container to a specific height.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
        <p class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, sed. Ducimus at ex quo tenetur accusamus cupiditate accusantium officiis. Recusandae libero natus similique ea amet aut quae accusamus, neque ad!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I quite get what you want your result to be. But if you just wanna show the bottom of the child you can simply put `bottom: 0` on your child since you're using positioning. It's always good to use padding instead of translate, since translate can quicky mess your entire site up.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, sed. Ducimus at exquotenetur accusamus cupiditate accusantium officiis. Recusandae libero natus similique ea amet aut quae accusamus, neque ad!
  </p>
</div>
```